# setting the proxy?

Tags: java, android, proxy

I am making a broswer type app i want to set the proxy only for this browser

I tried to modify global proxy by using this code but it does not work

```
System.getProperties().put("http.proxyHost", "someProxyURL");
System.getProperties().put("http.proxyPort", "someProxyPort");
System.getProperties().put("http.proxyUser", "someUserName");
System.getProperties().put("http.proxyPassword", "somePassword");
System.getProperties().put("http.proxySet", "true");
```

So I looked at `proxySelector` class and I really don't understand how to set the proxy for my brower

I know there is a hidden class in `ProxySelector` in `com.android.settings/.ProxySelector`

But I have to manually entered the proxy.

Is there any way so that i can configure proxy only for mybrowser(Just a Webview) ??

Please Help. Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488338/webview-android-proxy

Comment: @Robert Thanks for your response I have found a solution which open a hidden activity com.android.settings.ProxySelector. Now I can set The proxy. But this activity does not have username/password field Can you guide me how can i set usename/password field so that i can open a webpage in webview. Now webview say forbidden because username/password is not set?

Comment: @Robert I looked at your link also but it always giving null on network Object.

Comment: Worth noting here that http.proxySet is an urban myth. Setting it has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

```
System.getProperties().put("http.proxyUser", "someUserName");
System.getProperties().put("http.proxyPassword", "somePassword");
```

These dont' work in the JDK, only in the Apache HTTP client.

```
System.getProperties().put("http.proxySet", "true");
```

This is an urban myth. It appears in some early Java books but has never done anything in the JDK. It is a relic of the defunct HotJavaBean browser c. 1998.

Answer (score -1):

You should use it like

```
Authenticator.setDefault(
   new Authenticator() {
      public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
         return new PasswordAuthentication(
              authUser, authPassword.toCharArray());
     }
   }
);

System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", someProxyURl);
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", someProxyPort);
System.setProperty("http.proxyUser", someProxyUser);
System.setProperty("http.proxyPassword", someProxyPassword);
....
```

Comment: `proxyUser` and `proxyPassword` are for the Apache HTTP client. They do nothing in the JDK. Setting the `Authenticator` is sufficient.