# JWebBrowser - Set Proxy

Tags: java, proxy, jwebbrowser

I am using a JWebBrowser in this program that I am trying to create and I was just wondering how to set a proxy through JWebBrowser. I looked at this post [setting the proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10108371/setting-the-proxy) and tried it, but it didn't work. I've tried to Google this and I couldn't find anything. If anyone has any solutions, it would be much appreciated to share. Thanks.

Here is the code that I was using to try and make it work:

```
        System.getProperties().put("http.proxyHost", proxy.getIp());
    System.getProperties().put("http.proxyPort", Integer.toString(proxy.getPort()));
    System.getProperties().put("http.proxyUser", "");
    System.getProperties().put("http.proxyPassword", "");
    System.getProperties().put("proxySet", "true");
```

And yes, it is a valid proxy. I tried going to an ip checker (through JWebBrowser) to make sure my ip actually changed, but it didn't. If anyone can help me it would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Windows: All Browser instances, regardless of native renderer, automatically use Windows' global proxy settings. These settings can be changed at any time in the Windows Control Panel.

This is from www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#xpthemes. You can set the global proxy setting from Java best via manipulating the registry calling "reg add".