# WebView Opens URL Even If Proxy Server Is Not Running

Tags: android, proxy, android-webview, proxy-server

I did set **Proxy** for my application's **`WebView`** as said in [This Link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488338/webview-android-proxy)

But if i turn off my proxy server then instead of showing error page it connects to that page and opens up the page.

Is there anything **extra** i need to specify while setting/using proxy for **`WebView`**.

Thanks in advance :)