# programmatically setting proxy for webview in android

Tags: android, proxy, android-webview

How to set proxy for a webview programmatically which works for all api's in android. Any example code or sources would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Check this: [WebView android proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488338/webview-android-proxy)

HttpHost can be created like:

```
HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("someproxy", 8080);
```

And pased to the method written in the link.

Hope it helps,