# Proxying Android webview (not on system level)

Tags: android, webview, proxy, nanohttpd

Are there anyways to programmatically proxy Android Webview requests within an application only? (I want all requests to be passed through an embedded proxy) All of the solutions i have found so far are system level and will change proxy settings for the whole android device, something i do not want.

Comment: set Webview to load data from localhost

Comment: oh, how would i go about that?

Comment: It's not a real proxy but you could set the content to be sth like `http://localhost:8888/?url=http://www.google.com` and have a proxy like thing run on port 8888 that loads from given url-encoded address.

Comment: Or you do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488338/webview-android-proxy