# Webview not connecting to nanohttpd

Tags: java, android, webview, proxy, nanohttpd

I am attempting to use a web view with an embedded Nanohttpd server. I can get both to work , but not with each other.

I can send the WebWiew requests to other proxies that are not embedded , this works. 
or i can send requests from firefox to the embedded proxy and return a modified response.

But i can't send webview requests to the embedded proxy, has anyone tried or encountered this before?

The only hypothesis i can come up with for the reason it fails is i may need to run the server in the background or on another thread?

I'm using code from here for setting the webview proxy, which i can confirm does work [WebView android proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488338/webview-android-proxy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)
You can use `AsyncTask<?,?,?>` to run your embedded server in the background of the UI thread. I assume your embedded server called "HelloServer", here is a example code:

```
public class ToRunServer extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
    HelloServer helloServer = null;
    try {
        helloServer = new HelloServer();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        HelloServer.start();
        System.out.println("SERVER START TRIED");
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("SERVER START FAILED");
        return false;
    }
}

protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
}
}
```

Then in your UI class or activity class just add a line into your code:

```
Boolean isServerRunning = new ToRunServer().execute().get();
```

Comment: That's perfect, it runs flawlessly now!