# Android WebView set proxy programmatically on Android-L

Tags: android-webview, android-5.0-lollipop

So [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19979578/android-webview-set-proxy-programatically-kitkat) works up up to Android 4.4.4, however, the code ceases to work on Android-L developer preview, does anyone have some working code for Android-L? Or any tips on how I might get to the code myself?

This is the current method I use for KitKat (and works)

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
private static boolean setKitKatWebViewProxy(WebView webView, String host, int port) {
    Context appContext = webView.getContext().getApplicationContext();
    System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", host);
    System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", port + "");
    System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", host);
    System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", port + "");
    try {
        Class applictionCls = Class.forName(FinalVariables.APPLICATION_CANONICAL_NAME);
        Field loadedApkField = applictionCls.getField("mLoadedApk");
        loadedApkField.setAccessible(true);
        Object loadedApk = loadedApkField.get(appContext);
        Class loadedApkCls = Class.forName("android.app.LoadedApk");
        Field receiversField = loadedApkCls.getDeclaredField("mReceivers");
        receiversField.setAccessible(true);
        ArrayMap receivers = (ArrayMap) receiversField.get(loadedApk);
        for (Object receiverMap : receivers.values()) {
            for (Object rec : ((ArrayMap) receiverMap).keySet()) {
                Class clazz = rec.getClass();
                if (clazz.getName().contains("ProxyChangeListener")) {
                    Method onReceiveMethod = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("onReceive", Context.class, Intent.class);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Proxy.PROXY_CHANGE_ACTION);

                    /*********** optional, may be need in future *************/
                    final String CLASS_NAME = "android.net.ProxyProperties";
                    Class cls = Class.forName(CLASS_NAME);
                    Constructor constructor = cls.getConstructor(String.class, Integer.TYPE, String.class);
                    constructor.setAccessible(true);
                    Object proxyProperties = constructor.newInstance(host, port, null);
                    intent.putExtra("proxy", (Parcelable) proxyProperties);
                    /*********** optional, may be need in future *************/

                    onReceiveMethod.invoke(rec, appContext, intent);
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
        String exceptionAsString = sw.toString();
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage());
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, exceptionAsString);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
        String exceptionAsString = sw.toString();
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage());
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, exceptionAsString);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
        String exceptionAsString = sw.toString();
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage());
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, exceptionAsString);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
        String exceptionAsString = sw.toString();
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage());
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, exceptionAsString);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
        String exceptionAsString = sw.toString();
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage());
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, exceptionAsString);
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
        String exceptionAsString = sw.toString();
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage());
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, exceptionAsString);
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
        String exceptionAsString = sw.toString();
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage());
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, exceptionAsString);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Remove the the optional block of my [previous solusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19979578/android-webview-set-proxy-programatically-kitkat) for kitkat should work on android L-preview, because the ProxyProperties class could not be found in android L-preview any more.
So the new solution is:

```
public static void setLPreViewWebViewProxy(Context context, String host, int port) {
    System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", host);
    System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", port + "");
    try {
        Context appContext = context.getApplicationContext();
        Class applictionClass = Class.forName("android.app.Application");
        Field mLoadedApkField = applictionClass.getDeclaredField("mLoadedApk");
        mLoadedApkField.setAccessible(true);
        Object mloadedApk = mLoadedApkField.get(appContext);
        Class loadedApkClass = Class.forName("android.app.LoadedApk");
        Field mReceiversField = loadedApkClass.getDeclaredField("mReceivers");
        mReceiversField.setAccessible(true);
        ArrayMap receivers = (ArrayMap) mReceiversField.get(mloadedApk);
        for (Object receiverMap : receivers.values()) {
            for (Object receiver : ((ArrayMap) receiverMap).keySet()) {
                Class clazz = receiver.getClass();
                if (clazz.getName().contains("ProxyChangeListener")) {
                    Method onReceiveMethod = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("onReceive", Context.class, Intent.class);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Proxy.PROXY_CHANGE_ACTION);
                    onReceiveMethod.invoke(receiver, appContext, intent);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Just a word of caution... this works fine on Android L and even on Lollipop but it does it by changing the application-wide proxy settings (because of the `System.setProperty()` calls), meaning that it affects more things than just your WebViews. Other components like the Apache HttpClient or 3rd libraries in your app may start using the proxy too.

Answer (score 4):

Android L added an **android.net.ProxyInfo** class for receiving proxy
information instead of **android.net.ProxyProperties** class.

So, simple patch for your code could looks like that:

```
- final String CLASS_NAME = "android.net.ProxyProperties";
+ String CLASS_NAME;
+ if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
+   CLASS_NAME = "android.net.ProxyProperties";
+ } else {
+   CLASS_NAME = "android.net.ProxyInfo";
+ } 
  Class cls = Class.forName(CLASS_NAME);
```

See details here:

[Start using public API for receiving proxy information](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!msg/chromium-reviews/y2qXhT-T6rA/Ho6lMtzqNogJ)