# Proxy set in settings of emulator not reflecting in webview

Tags: android, webview, proxy

I have set proxy settings in settings>..>apn>TelKila 
changed proxy and port, and now internet is working fine on stock browser of emulator. 
But it is not working in a webview I created in an app, and throwing **error code 407** (Need proxy details). While same things worked while I tried a few months back. Any change in APIs? Using **android 4.0.3 on emulator**.

Consulted this question, but it shows how to set proxy programatically, which is not what I want.
[WebView android proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488338/webview-android-proxy)

Answer (score 0):

you don't change programatically proxy, just use one from already existing settings. [Android Webview set proxy programatically Kitkat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19979578/android-webview-set-proxy-programatically-kitka) The other way in Eclipse: 
 Run Configuration> Android Application > App > Target > Additional Emulator Command Line Options: -http-proxy http://myproxy:3128