# Setting the proxy for android's DownloadManager class

Tags: android, proxy

I have an app with a WebView, which downloads videos and plays them in a VideoView.

To manage the downloads I use android's handy `DownloadManager` API.
Unfortunately in some situations I need to use a proxy.

I have successfully set up the proxy for the WebView using reflection as [detailed in this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488338/webview-android-proxy), but I am not sure how I can set the `DownloadManager` to use a proxy as well..

Is this possible?
If not, what are my alternatives?

Thanks

Comment: @Daniel: You cannot specify a proxy for a `DownloadManager.Request`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to do this with the `DownloadManager` so I ended up implementing my own (simplified) download manager using an `AsyncTask`.

It's possible then to pass a `Proxy` object to `Url.openConnection` as below:

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, 
                        new InetSocketAddress(proxyHost, proxyPort));
URL url = new URL(src);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(proxy);
```

Once you've got the proxied connection you can download content as per usual.