# Intercepting http requests from javascript running on WebView

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I am developing an app that has an embbed webpage that runs javascript.
The javascript executes requests, and I would like to intercept them. I need this because I need the user to use the webview without an internet connection. I want to save the requests and execute later when he is connected.

What I have tried:

- `WebViewClient:` this class has `shouldInterceptRequest` but it only provides the url, I need more info (headers and body).

  ```
  mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
      @Override
      public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view,
              String url) {
          return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, url);
      }
  });
  ```
- Setting a [custom proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18453384) and creating a SocketServer to listen to the proxy port and intercept the request. This approach is too risky for me.

Therefore I would like to know if there is another way.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you give an example of such a javascript request? Are you familiar with the WebView JavaScriptInterface?

Comment: The .js is provided by a third party, and I cannot change it. I don't see how JavaScriptInterface can help me.

Comment: You were not asked to change or show the javascript. Only to give an example of how such request would look like.