# How to set an exclusion list on a programmatically configured proxy on KitKat?

Tags: android, android-networking

I am using [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18453384/704836) to setup a proxy for my WebView on Android and it is working well. I have modified the code to use an exclusion list. On devices using the android.net.ProxyProperties I am passing an exclusion list like ".google.com,.bing.com" and on devices using the System properties I am passing "*.google.com|*.bing.com". It is all working fine on ICS, and Lollipop but I can not get it to work on KitKat. I don't have 4.2/4.3 devices to test on but I'll try it on an emulator later, either way their code is the same as ICS for setting the proxy.

My set proxy code on KitKat looks like this:

```
private static boolean setProxyKK(WebView webView, String host, int port, String applicationClassName) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Setting proxy with 4.4-4.4.4 API.");

        Context appContext = webView.getContext().getApplicationContext();
     System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", host);
    System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", port + "");
    System.setProperty("http.nonProxyHosts", "*.google.com|*.bing.com");
        try {
            Class applictionCls = Class.forName(applicationClassName);
            Field loadedApkField = applictionCls.getField("mLoadedApk");
            loadedApkField.setAccessible(true);
            Object loadedApk = loadedApkField.get(appContext);
            Class loadedApkCls = Class.forName("android.app.LoadedApk");
            Field receiversField = loadedApkCls.getDeclaredField("mReceivers");
            receiversField.setAccessible(true);
            ArrayMap receivers = (ArrayMap) receiversField.get(loadedApk);
            for (Object receiverMap : receivers.values()) {
                for (Object rec : ((ArrayMap) receiverMap).keySet()) {
                    Class clazz = rec.getClass();
                    if (clazz.getName().contains("ProxyChangeListener")) {
                        Method onReceiveMethod = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("onReceive", Context.class, Intent.class);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Proxy.PROXY_CHANGE_ACTION);

                        /*********** optional, may be need in future *************/
                        final String CLASS_NAME = "android.net.ProxyProperties";
                        Class cls = Class.forName(CLASS_NAME);
                        Constructor constructor = cls.getConstructor(String.class, Integer.TYPE, String.class);
                        constructor.setAccessible(true);
                        Object proxyProperties = constructor.newInstance(host, port, ".google.com,.bing.com");
                        intent.putExtra("proxy", (Parcelable) proxyProperties);
                        /*********** optional, may be need in future *************/

                        onReceiveMethod.invoke(rec, appContext, intent);
                    }
                }
            }

            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Setting proxy with >= 4.4 API successful!");
            return true;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
            String exceptionAsString = sw.toString();
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage());
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, exceptionAsString);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
            String exceptionAsString = sw.toString();
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage());
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, exceptionAsString);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
            String exceptionAsString = sw.toString();
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage());
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, exceptionAsString);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
            String exceptionAsString = sw.toString();
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage());
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, exceptionAsString);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
            String exceptionAsString = sw.toString();
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage());
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, exceptionAsString);
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
            String exceptionAsString = sw.toString();
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage());
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, exceptionAsString);
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
            String exceptionAsString = sw.toString();
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage());
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, exceptionAsString);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Any idea of what might be wrong with it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the issue. I had to comment out a part which wasn't even needed. The part to comment out is:

```
/*********** optional, may be need in future *************/
                    final String CLASS_NAME = "android.net.ProxyProperties";
                    Class cls = Class.forName(CLASS_NAME);
                    Constructor constructor = cls.getConstructor(String.class, Integer.TYPE, String.class);
                    constructor.setAccessible(true);
                    Object proxyProperties = constructor.newInstance(host, port, ".google.com,.bing.com");
                    intent.putExtra("proxy", (Parcelable) proxyProperties);
/*********** optional, may be need in future *************/
```