# How to configure a proxy exclusion list on Android non-programmatically?

Tags: android, firefox, proxy, firefox-addon, android-4.4-kitkat

I'm running Android Kit-Kat 4.4.2. I've been able to configure a global proxy using the settings.db database in data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases, which I've been manually altering using adb. To do this I've done the following:

- Inserted a value into the *global* table with _id=99, name='http_proxy', and value='[proxy_host]:[proxy_port]' (obviously replacing [proxy_host] and [proxy_port] with their appropriate values).
- Rebooted. This automatically generates rows in the *global* table with names: global_http_proxy_host, global_http_proxy_port, global_proxy_pac_url, and global_http_proxy_exclusion_list.
- The global_http_proxy_host and global_http_proxy_port rows have been automatically given the correct settings (i.e. [proxy_host] and [proxy_port], respectively). The rest are empty.

The proxy works. For reference, I'm using Firefox for Android version 44.0.1 to test that it works. As long as the network.proxy.type setting has a value of 5 then this global proxy is respected (see [this Mozilla knowledge-base](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.proxy.type)).

When I enter a URL into the global_http_proxy_exclusion_list and test to see if it's been excluded, I'm still routed through the proxy. I thought that maybe I needed to reboot the device for the update to take, but on reboot the global_http_proxy_exclusion_list resets so that it is empty once more.

I've tried doing a web search for this property but I just get links to source code, which is not helpful in this instance.

I've also found [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32019545/how-to-set-an-exclusion-list-on-a-programmatically-configured-proxy-on-kitkat) which configures a proxy exclusion list programmatically. If this is the only way to configure such a list then it will make do, but I'd rather avoid it if I can.

I've been able to specifically configure Firefox with a proxy exclusion list using the network.proxy.no_proxies_on configuration option (and setting network.proxy.type to 1), but would like to know if there's a way to set a global proxy.

Use of an Android app would be an acceptable solution to this problem. I've installed ProxyDroid and configured a proxy but, as far as I can tell, this does nothing (or Firefox just doesn't respect the proxy). *(For anybody who might believe that using ProxyDroid is the right answer here: I have rooted my device but still get messages from ProxyDroid saying that a rooted device is required. Is this normal?)*

**Is there any way for me to configure a proxy exclusion list in Android non-programmatically?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for your global_http_proxy_exclusion value to persist, I think you need to remove the old http_proxy entry. (In other words, only set the global_http_proxy_* keys.)

ConnectivityService implements a handleDeprecatedGlobalHttpProxy() method that looks at the old http_proxy key before generating a new ProxyInfo that gets persisted to the global_http_proxy_* keys. The ProxyInfo this method generates always uses a blank exclusion list, which I think is what's overwriting the value you set once Android boots up.

Running Lollipop, my exclusion list persisted after reboot when I removed http_proxy and just relied on the global settings.

Comment: Brilliant. For posterity: Addresses in the exclusion list need to be formatted as e.g. www.wikipedia.org. (It didn't seem to work if I left off the "www.".) Multiple sites can be separated with a comma.