# how to set proxy for web view android 5 and higher

Tags: android, webview, proxy

I am trying to set a proxy on a webview level, found issue with android 5.

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488338/webview-android-proxy) stackoverflow post I adapted the solution from Jimmy Dee.

This works great with all lower devices such as 4.2 but it throws the following error on android 5 and up:

> Using no proxy configuration due to
>   exception:java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'java.lang.Object android.os.Bundle.get(java.lang.String)' on a
>   null object reference

If anybody has update code for android 5 and up it will be a big help.