# Android WebView Proxy

Tags: java, android, webview, proxy, webkit

how can i do loading page with proxy in Android WebView?

I have this code:

```
    private WebView webView = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        this.webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.my);

        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webView.setWebViewClient(
                new WebViewClient() {
                    @Override
                    public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
                        handler.proceed();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                        view.loadUrl(url);
                        return false;
                    }
                }
        );

        webView.loadUrl("https://...");
    }
```

WebView has any default params to do this?
Can someone help me?
I am a newbie in JAVA

Comment: Please check out this link. It might help.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488338/webview-android-proxy